# Only limited number of unanswered questions showing up on Stackoverflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Is any one else getting only 3 questions in the unanswered list. There should be 33,470.

I have set it to not show ignore tags, but I do not have many of them.

The number varies between 1 and 5. I am using IE8

http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/1948/stackoverflow.jpg

For a larger picture of the screen dump check this link http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/1948/stackoverflow.jpg

Here is a list of my ignore tags:

http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/3937/stackoverflow1.jpg

Here is what happens when I ask it not to hide my ignore tags:

http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/7069/stackoverflow2.jpg

Only 5 items only 1 relevant

For a larger picture of the screen dump check this linkhttp://img220.imageshack.us/img220/7069/stackoverflow2.jpg

Comment: Just increased to 4

Comment: @Jeff: Have updated with relevant screen shots.

Comment: yep, everything here is by-design. the last shot you are on the "my tags" tab. Your interests are very narrow, so there is very little for you. Switch to the "newest" tab, or "votes" tab.

Comment: Wow, +200KB screenshots. That's heavy.

Comment: @Jeff: On the last shot I was on the newest tab. I have c# and wcf as "interesting tags". I have also deleted all of my ignored tags.

Comment: @Jeff: Fixed now. Somehow my default page size had been set to 5 for unanswered questions only. When I selected page size from the icons it got reset.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking at the "My Tags" tab. I don't know what tags you subscribe to, but if it's niche enough, this is probably the case.

There are currently 33,472 questions that are unanswered. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=newest).

Update: Yeah, you definitely have `hide ignore tags` checked in your profile. This happens after the page is loaded, so that's why you see so few.

Comment: No it is newest, I have c# as one of my tags

Comment: @Shiraz: Time for a screenshot!

Comment: @Eric How do I upload a screen shot?

Comment: You can use an imagehost like imageshack.us and then use the image tag.

Answer (score 1):

I get all of them.

Comment: Which browser do you use?